# Alamofire service calls multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/writecomment.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    var success = 0
                    if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                            success = successInteger
                            if success == 1
                            {
                                //succes
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                return
            }
        }
```

This is connected to an UIButton action

It **SOMETIMES** triggers service calls multiple times when user tap button.

How to prevent multiple calls?

Comment: Try setting breakpoints and investigate if the line is called multiple times or not.

Comment: check button action. it should be `touch up inside`

Comment: Its an issue with button itself, I dont know if there is a better approach but just check if there is an ongoing call with a boolean value, set it true when a request begins, and then set it false again once you receive the callback.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla it is already touch up inside

Comment: @emrepun can you show me an example please?

Comment: Is the action called multiple times?

Comment: @paper1111 I guess so

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz can you do a print statement to see and not just "guess"?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz add your button action code please

Comment: @AnkurLahiry I already added check question

Comment: Sorry I just saw it, Yash's approach in the answers should be fine @UtkuDalmaz

Answer (score 4):

Example::

```
var isAPICalling = false

  @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if isAPICalling == false
   {
       isAPICalling = true
       self.APICalling() // Your API calling method
   }
 }
```

In `APICalling()` method set `isAPICalling = false` when you get response.

OTHER OPTION :

Use `ActivityIndicator` when you request that time start indicator and after response stop indicator. So you cannot able to tap on button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing without using flag, if you have button outlet then just make button state selected when button click action is performed.

then call API and once you get the response make button state normal. so it will call only once when user click on button.

```
    @IBAction func btnApiAction(_ sender: Any) {
       if btnAPI.isSelected == false {
          btnAPI.isSelected = true            
          //Call API here
       }else {
        //Do nothing here
       }
     }
```

if API Call is get failed or if you are getting any error then also change button state to normal so user can click again on button.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `UIButton` when you call API. And enable back when api call finished.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    Alamofire.request(/* Params */) { response in 
         sender.isEnabled = true
         // parse response - response.result
    }
}
```

I prefer to add `ActivityIndicatorView` to the button view, and remove when finished for better UX.